# Как объявить нужное количество переменных?

Tags: c++

Допустим, у меня есть программа, я ее запрограммировал так чтобы она брала координаты курсора и переносила их в другую переменную. 
Начинаю, "вносить" координаты, и я хочу чтобы координаты курсора взялись 6 раз, однако мне понадобиться надо это 6 переменных. А если мне надо чтобы он  зафиксировал координаты курсора 1000 раз? Мне придется 1000 переменных объявлять?
И вот как мне объявить нужное количество переменных?

Comment: если есть одна ручка, то можно хранить в кармане, а если есть 1000 ручек, то где хранить?... Наверное в каком то контейнере..., а не  в 1000 карманах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас спасут динамические массивы :) - например, `vector`, раз уж вы работаете на C++.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, меня давно этот вопрос волновал

Answer (score 1):

В С++ можно использовать не только отдельные переменные, но и их массивы - то есть это одно имя у многих переменных. Например,

```
int massiv[100];
```

дает вам 100 переменных типа `int` - вы просто, упрощая, должны указывать ее порядковый номер от 0 до 99 - `massiv[0]`, `massiv[1]` и так далее.

Comment: не было вопроса  о том, что из себя представляет массив...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну он спросил о переменных - по вопросу понятно, что о массивах он не знает. Вот я и рассказал, как объявить много переменных сразу ))

Comment: Про массивы я конечно знаю))), но в моей задаче это решение использовать можно, спасибо

Comment: @Mikhailo , предпологаю, что вообше не существует  человека,  изучающего С++ и не знающего о массивах, но как правильно заметил  Harry, в данном случаи спасают только динамические массивы(контейнеры), а не просто массивы, поскольку  только во время выполнения становится известно  какого размера должен быть этот массив...